# Proving discontinutiy with epsilons and deltas.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I never actually had to show a function was discontinuous before, but trying to.. stumped me. I tried with the funtion $$f(x)= \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x\leq 1\\ x+1 &\mbox{if } x > 1\end{cases}$$ at the point $x=1$. After all, $|f(x)-f(1)|=|x-1|<\delta<\varepsilon$, but only for the left hand side. On the other hand, $|f(x)-f(1)|=|x+1-1|=|x|$..? I'm not sure what to do!

Comment: You can show that left and right limit at $x=1$ are not the same. Or you have to do it with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prove that a function is discontinuous, you need only exhibit an $\varepsilon>0$ where the condition fails for all $\delta>0$. In this case, take $\varepsilon=1$. Then, for any $\delta>0$, $0<|x-1|<\delta$ is equivalent to $1-\delta<x<1+\delta$, and so, picking $x=1+\frac{\delta}{2}$, $|f\left(1+\frac{\delta}{2}\right)-f\left(1\right)|=|1+\frac{\delta}{2}+1-1|=|1+\frac{\delta}{2}|=1+\frac{\delta}{2}>1=\varepsilon$. Therefore, $f$ is not continuous at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Statement: "f is continuous at $1$" means:
For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(1)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-1| < \delta$.

To say that "f is not continuous at $1$" means:
There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that, for every $\delta > 0$ there is at least one $x$ for which $|x-1| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(1)| > \epsilon$.

There definitely exists such $\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon = 1/2$. For each $\delta > 0$, you are obliged to find $x$ in $(1-1/2,1+1/2)$ for which $|f(x)-f(1)| > \epsilon$. If, for each $\delta > 0$, you can find such $x$ ($x$ will depend on $\delta$), then $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$.